# Why is the tab bar disappearing?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

My current setup of viewcontrollers are:
 tab view > navigation controller > table view controller > navigation view controller > cell details. Please see
[The current setup of viewcontrollers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRd7s.png)

I used to have: 
tab view > navigation controller > table view controller > cell details
and then everything was fine.

The issue is that I need a custom action to happen when the user presses the back button, and to do this i added a nav controller between the "table view" and the "cell details". And thats when the tab bar disappeared. I understand this seems to be "normal" behaviour, but that don´t help me much. Please help.

The code that segues to the detail view controller. (I use the storyboard, so light on code for these things)

```
@IBAction func add(sender: AnyObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TableViewToDetailView",    sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: added code, can add more if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the right question was kind of hard to ask. using Tsb Bar Controllers with Navigation Controllers and View Controllers os too tricky and certain things a re not allowed and there is a lot of terminology, and, there are many different types of segues,and there are many different kinds of consequences for doing certain things.

I found the correct procedure (answer) in the second part of this two part series:

1. [Storyboards Tutorial for iOS: Part 1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/464-storyboards-tutorial-for-ios-part-1)
2. [Storyboards Tutorial for iOS: Part 2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/462-storyboards-tutorial-for-ios-part-2)

Summary of the procedure: 
Embed the source and destination View Controllers in Navigation Controllers, then create unwind segues (methods with the signature`@IBAction func methodname(_ segue:)`) in the source view controller. Then, from the destination View Controller, control-click from the navigation bar button (or any view required to trigger a return to the first view controller) to the Exit object above the view controller then pick the correct action name from the popup menu.  The unwind segue will be accessible from the Document Outline and can be given an identifier to use in `prepare(for:sender:)` in case data needs to be sent to the from the destination view controller. Also, the segue from the first view Controller to the second navigation controller must be modal.

Answer (score 7):

It happens when `hideTabBarOnPush` property is true(in code) or `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` is checked on storyboard for the controller you are pushing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But unfortunately I don´t think this is the answer. I have looked at all the viewcontrollers, (I use the storyboard and not code) and none of them has "hide bottom bar on push" ticked. I can post some images if that help you believe me :)

Comment: i agree. this didn't work for me when i did it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue I met although maybe not quite the same as yours but hope it may help. When view controller A presents view controller B, the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property of B could be overridden by the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property of A. I fixed it by setting B's modal style.